# Only 1 button enable in ListView, custom adapter

Tags: android-listview, custom-adapter

I run into a problem where I need to enable my button in the ListView. The weird thing is :

```
 public class CookingStepAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CookingStep> {

...
       private void addButtonToList(Button clock, Button skip){
            if (list_clock_button == null) {
                list_clock_button = new ArrayList<Button>();
                iterate = 0;
            }
            if (list_skip_button == null)
                list_skip_button = new ArrayList<Button>();
            list_clock_button.add(clock);
            list_skip_button.add(skip);

            clock.setEnabled(true);
            skip.setEnabled(true);

            list_clock_button.get(0).setEnabled(true);
            list_clock_button.get(0).setFocusable(true);
            list_clock_button.get(0).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            list_clock_button.get(0).invalidate();

            list_skip_button.get(0).setEnabled(true);
            list_skip_button.get(0).setFocusable(true);
            list_skip_button.get(0).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            list_skip_button.get(0).postInvalidate();
        }
}
```

When I set enable with the `list_clock_button.get(0)`,  it's not working at all. But `clock.setEnabled(true);` actually worked.

But then I only want the first button of the ListView enabled, that makes the first option more fit in this situation. The second option works, but it made all the buttons enabled, that's not what I want. I did recheck the first button address, and it matched `list_clock_button.get(0)`, why it's not working.

EDIT :

Here's my function getView :

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cooking_steps_and_timer, parent, false);

        final Button button = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button_timer);
        final TextView timer = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cooking_timer);
        final Button skipButton = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button_skip);
        TextView stepContent = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.cooking_step_content);

        final CookingStep step = list.get(position);
        String stepOrder = (String) context.getResources().getText(R.string.step_order) + " " + step.getOrder();
        String content = "<b>" + stepOrder + ":</b>" + " " + step.getContent() + "\n";
        stepContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));

        if (step.getTimer() == null || step.getTimer() == 0){
            timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            skipButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {

            //myTimer = new CookingTimer(step.getTimer());
            timer.setText(step.getMyTimer().toString());
            step.setCountDown(new CountDownTimer(step.getTimer() * 60000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    step.getMyTimer().tick();
                    timer.setText(step.getMyTimer().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    nextButtonEnable();
                }
            });

            button.setText(R.string.button_available);
            skipButton.setText(R.string.skip_button_content);

            addButtonToList(button, skipButton);
            //button.setEnabled(true);

            list_clock_button.get(0).setEnabled(true);

            button.requestFocusFromTouch();
            button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                        if (!button.isPressed()) {
                            button.setPressed(true);
                            button.setText(R.string.button_available);
                            step.getCountDown().start();
                        } else {
                            button.setPressed(false);
                            button.setText(R.string.button_pressed);
                            step.getCountDown().cancel();

                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });

            skipButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        step.getCountDown().cancel();
                        nextButtonEnable();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
        return rowView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of all buttons getting enabled is you are setting all of them enable yourself. To set any particular button enable you have to check the id or the item position to set that particular button to enable.
Like this for example:-

```
if(clock.getID == R.id.some_id_in_xml){
    clock.setEnabled(true);
}
```

But before that you have to check the position of the item to select the desired item in the list.

Comment: But I did save them into the List, and the references inside this List match the references of the buttons. And the (Button clock, Button skip) acquired by  
`final Button button = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button_timer);` 
And, if what you stated is the problem, then the first options shouldn't work too.

Comment: can you provide the code of getView() function of your adapter.

Comment: I added my getView into my question

Comment: You don't have to add buttons in the list just to set them enable or disable. just add two data members in your `CookingStep` class like isButtonEnable and isSkipButtonEnable and set there values according to your needs and then set your buttons properties according to these flags. Because `ListView` always refreshes its view when scrolled and you have to reset all properties according to the arraylist of data. in your case `CookingStep`.

Comment: That's weird even if ListView reset all properties, since I made that list static. So you mean that I can't manipulate the data inside the adapter ? Because I don't even know where should I do this, if not inside adapter, since in that is the only way I can set up button listener. The list have many items, between these items, there 're those who have button and those who have not, so I want that only one button enable at the beginning, and then when user push it, it will be disable and the next button will be enabled.

Comment: I 've managed some how, but that's not the way I want. What I did is I add the 2 buttons into my data object, which is `CookingStep`, and then I manually set the enable state of the button inside the Activity :( Are there any else method ? This's not totally clean, look like rubbish to me, but it worked !

Comment: The thing is. `ListView` doesn't change its properties but the items are removed and added while scrolling up and down. So, there should be some place where properties of list items could be saved and could be accessed by the `ListView` when creating its item. The thing you are doing is right because you have to only change the `CookingStep` values and the listView will set its items according to the data provided.

Comment: wait, I mean that I have to include the whole button object inside my data class `CookingStep`. I tried to change the state using only the boolean variable, but didn't work. I even called `invalidate()` and `postInvalidate`, but the button didn't change state. So i have to include the button inside the data class, and enable it manually

Comment: Oh. You don't have to do that. just put boolean variables and when you change them call `yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`. This will update the listView and your listitems will change their properties according to the booleans.