# Android Adapter and getView behavior

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, getview

I'm currently confusing about adapter in android, especially the function getView 's behavior.

I came across many answer that stated that the getView() function will be called whenever the list change, like when scrolling the listview.

Then I put this inside the getView function :

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.v("GET VIEW", "" + " ITEM accordingly " + position);
    ...
}
```

and when I run, this is what I received inside logcat :

```
09-06 17:18:23.812    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 0
09-06 17:18:23.848    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 0
09-06 17:18:23.851    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 0
09-06 17:18:23.868    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 0
09-06 17:18:23.874    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 1
09-06 17:18:23.880    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 2
09-06 17:18:23.887    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 3
09-06 17:18:23.894    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 4
09-06 17:18:23.903    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 5
09-06 17:18:23.910    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 6
09-06 17:18:23.930    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 0
09-06 17:18:23.932    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 1
09-06 17:18:23.937    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 2
09-06 17:18:23.942    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 3
09-06 17:18:23.948    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 4
09-06 17:18:23.958    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 5
09-06 17:18:23.968    3555-3555/com.example.nguyenquanganh.cookingassistance V/GET VIEW﹕ ITEM accordingly 6
```

what's more, it didn't print anything else when I scroll the list. The above output is when I launch the activity, and I didn't do anything else.

So could anyone explain to me, why there're several calls for getView on the same Item ? and why getView didn't get called when I scrolled the list ?

Comment: what you're doing in the method? see those links, there are useful: http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview and http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: In the method I just bind the data into listView. It run, but I want to find out more about the behavior of this method, since you could see the output in catlog, it's not expected at all.

Answer (score 0):

Views in list view is reused, since you have only 7 items in list view, list view will not call adapter's getView when it has get adequate information before. Try to increase your child count, view recycling will happen then.

Comment: yeah only 7 items, but each item have many line of text, so I still have to scroll to see all 7. But at the time it launch, it run getView on all 7 items. What's more, there 're some duplicate calls too, and item0 was called again and again many times. Why is that

Comment: Have you call notifyDataSetChanged in some place? This will cause system to reload views. These callbacks are called by system, so it's system behavior. For multiple loading of item 0, I guess maybe it wants to determine view size or something else. As for prefetch number, it's also determined by system, maybe the number is related to memory or other conditions, different phones have different view pool numbers. You have to look up android source for some clue.

Comment: No I didn't touch notifyDataSetChanged yet. And I have something wondering about, say if I have a button inside the listView, and then I declare some listener for it, like onTouchListener in getView, then does it means that if getView get called several times on the same item, then that button declare several time the OnTouchListener too ? If that's the case, then if I have some data saved in the adapter to keep track of some behavior, those data will lost or messed up too right ?

Comment: To the first question, when a view is reused, convertView passed in is not null (you have created before), you only needs to inflate one when it's null. For a reused view, you just fill stuff related to this view according to your data, including onTouchListener, so it's just a re-set. As to second question, surely you can use adapter to hold data, share the life time of adapter, as long as it's not garbage collected. I prefer to use adapter as a bridge between View and Model.

Comment: Ohhh so that's it. I understand that view part now. For the adapter holding the data, I thinks there're a few problems. I'm developing a personal project, inside the adapter I declared a static list of button. And when I run the activity for the first time, the buttons were added into the static list, I print it out to Log, and it do exist, however when I try to access this list again from the activity which create the adapter, it return null pointer.

Comment: And I didn't switch activity yet. Here's the link to that problem : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32390626/only-1-button-enable-in-listview-custom-adapter/32390771?noredirect=1#comment52652314_32390771). So I have to resolve the problem in an ugly way, included the button inside data class. Do you have any other way to solve this ? I just wanna keep my OOP structure clean